# WickedPdf encoding error in only production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, text, production

I'm novice in rails. I really get in trouble.

Because log isn't tell me what error is it.

I using Korea (UTF-8).

So I set meta tag

```
%meta{:content => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http-equiv" => "content-type"}/
```

and wickedpdf config

```
  format.pdf do
    pdf_config
    render pdf: "상담 일지-#{ Time.now.strftime("%m-%d %I%p")}.pdf",
           layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.haml',
           encoding: 'utf8'
  end
```

However

My pdf view in production env is folloing.

[image]

However my pdf view in development and staging env is following

[image]

I has been googling 5 hour. But It is really strange error. Anyone alse could help me?.....

Anyway, Thank you for listen my question! I hope you solve my problem.

Comment: Are you using any font for that purpose

Comment: I'm using bootstrap's default font : 

    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

Comment: Have you fixed it? I am facing same issue.